# Can I use the object in the same expression more than once without modifying it safely?

Tags: c++, operator-precedence

I've seen this example on C++ primer 5 edition which talks about smart pointers; I have class `StrBlobPtr` which works as a companion to `StrBlob`.

One of the members of `StrBlobPtr` is `deref`:

```
std::string& StrBlobPtr::deref() const
{
    auto p = check(curr, "dereference past end");
    return (*p)[curr]; // (*p) is the vector to which this object points
}
```

`check` returns a `std::shared_ptr` either null or pointing to an object.

- What I want to know only is whether I can make the return statement directly from calling `check` or not:

  ```
  std::string& StrblobPtr::deref() {
      return (*check(index_, "dereferencing unbound StrblobPtr!"))[index_];
  }
  ```
- So is it well-defined here using `index_` in the same expression twice without modifying it? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `index` twice in

```
return (*check(index_, "dereferencing unbound StrblobPtr!"))[index_];
```

fine as long as you are not modifying it.

What is not fine though is you are unconditionally indirecting the pointer.  You say `check` can return a null pointer.  Indirecting through a null pointer is undefined behavior.  You need to make sure you guard against that by checking the return value first.  If it is null then you either need to return a sentinel or throw an exception.

Comment: But `check` throw if the the temporary shared_ptr is null inside its body before returning it. Then is it OK?

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa Oh, then it is fine.  You said *returns a std::shared_ptr either null or pointing to an object* so I took that to mean `check` can actually return a null pointer.  If it only returns a valid pointer or throws, then you can indeed indirect through the pointer without issue.

Comment: I am sorry. It never returns a nullptr because inside its body a temporary `std::shared_ptr` is created and testes against `nullptr` value if so `throw` otherwise check the `index` if `index` is noot in range `throw` otherwise return that object.